# How to copy and rename folders using bash?

Tags: bash

I have many folders with similar names

```
sim00 
sim01
sim02
```

and more. I have a file that I want to copy from all of them named test.dat and copy them to a new folder named analysis and give them a new name , such as test_0.dat, test_1.dat and so on.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
counter=0; for value in "sim*/test.dat"; do cp "$value" "analysis/${value%.dat}_$counter.dat ; ((counter++)); done
```

However, this does not work. Can someone show me a different solution?

Comment: The star doesn't expand in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The rule "quote your variables" doesn't say you should quote wildcards, too. Enclosing the asterisk in double quotes prevents its expansion.

You also need to remove the path from the filename:

```
#! /bin/bash
counter=0
for file in sim*/test.dat; do
    cp "$file" analysis/test_"$counter".dat
    ((counter++))
done
```

Comment: This is giving me _0.dat, _1.dat, _2.dat, etc. instead of test_0.dat test_1.dat. Your solution works fine for me, but just for learning purposes, how do I get the filename in front of the _?